# Why does apt-mark showhold show two packages which are up-to-date

Tags: apt, server, package-management, updates

On an Ubuntu server with these specs:

```sh
user@server:~$ uname -mor
5.4.0-139-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux

user@server:~$  cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

everything is up-to-date:

```sh
user@server:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg InRelease
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

but apt shows two on-hold packages:

```sh
user@server:~$ sudo apt-mark showhold
docker-ce
docker-ce-cli
```

Both of them seem up-to-date:

```sh
user@server:~$ sudo apt-cache policy docker-ce
docker-ce:
  Installed: 5:23.0.1-1~ubuntu.18.04~bionic
  Candidate: 5:23.0.1-1~ubuntu.18.04~bionic
  Version table:
 *** 5:23.0.1-1~ubuntu.18.04~bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5:23.0.0-1~ubuntu.18.04~bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.23~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.22~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.21~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.20~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.19~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.18~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.17~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.16~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.15~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.14~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.13~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.12~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.11~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.10~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.7~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.6~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.2~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:20.10.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.15~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.14~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.13~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.12~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.11~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.10~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.7~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.6~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.2~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:19.03.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:18.09.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:18.09.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:18.09.7~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:18.09.6~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:18.09.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:18.09.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:18.09.3~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:18.09.2~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:18.09.1~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     5:18.09.0~3-0~ubuntu-bionic 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     18.06.3~ce~3-0~ubuntu 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     18.06.2~ce~3-0~ubuntu 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     18.06.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
     18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
```

I'm naturally wondering **why** does `apt-mark showhold` actually shows these two packages?

And if need be, how could I "clean" that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`apt-mark showhold` lists these packages because they have been marked as `hold`. This has been done by yourself, someone else with *root*-privileges or maybe by a script.

You can use

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package>
```

to cancel a previously set hold on a package to allow all actions again.

Please take a look into `man apt-mark`.

Comment: Thank your for your answer! I'll investigate why they have been marked as 'hold' then.